# WPF 4.5 empty TextBox validation on startup

Tags: wpf, textbox, .net-4.5, validationrule

I have a simple textbox with a validation rule, but a very weird behavior in a special situation.

If I use my code as this, and that my property is 0 (as it comes from db), it works as expected. The TextBox gets its red border at start.

> ```
> <TextBox x:Name="TxtOfferNumber"
>         IsReadOnly="{Binding SelectedOffer.IsValid}"
>         GotKeyboardFocus="TxtOfferNumber_GotKeyboardFocus"
>         GotMouseCapture="TxtOfferNumber_GotMouseCapture">
>     <TextBox.Text>
>         <Binding Path="OfferNumberLookup" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
>             <Binding.ValidationRules>
>                 <validators:OfferNumberValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
>             </Binding.ValidationRules>
>         </Binding>
>     </TextBox.Text>
> </TextBox>
> ```

My validation rule:

> ```
>    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
>     {
>         return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value as string) || Convert.ToInt32(value) != 0 ?
>             ValidationResult.ValidResult :
>             new ValidationResult(false, "Le numéro d'offre doit être informé!");
>     }
> ```

The problem is that I want this field as required, so empty is not valid.

As I want my validation rule to be:

> ```
>    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
>     {
>         return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value as string) && Convert.ToInt32(value) != 0 ?
>             ValidationResult.ValidResult :
>             new ValidationResult(false, "Le numéro d'offre doit être informé!");
>     }
> ```

And there is my big headache. The validation function returns correct result, but no red border. If I enter correct value and change to wrong value (empty or 0), now I get the red border.

Comment: if you want to check for empty string then you can also use string.IsNullorEmpty as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that the TextBox does not become validated on start-up, only when the input changes, a quick and dirty fix could be to set the Text (or binding property) to something correct and then something false during load.

Comment: Well, I did try this, but I guess I tried the wrong way. Tried again and it works as expected. Really hoped to find a cleaner correct way to do it. Can we say that this is a bug in WPF?

Comment: Oh, and sorry. Forgot to be polite. Thank you very much.